# How to set the background of all the childview of the expandablelistView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'd like to set the background of  an expandablelistView without changing the groupview.
Setting the background of each children item fails to meet the requirement. I think, the childView of the expandablelistView ,to some extend,is just like a listview ,and there must be somewhere to set it's background without having to set item by item. I'd be very appreciate for your kindness response ! thanks.

Comment: set background to the layout which you must be inflating in adapter.

Comment: thanks very much! however it is just setting the background of  the items not  the background of the   childView  as a whole

Comment: if you got the desired result than pls accept answer.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that it failed. And that's the very reason I'm here to ask. As you know, when you want to set  the background to a listview ,you'll just set it in the ListView  as a whole,rather than in the item xml file,which you'll inflate in adapter.

Comment: pls post the child item layout so that one could come to where the prob is??

Comment: the background is a 9 patch image. when I set it as the background of the item,then the the border between two items will becomes very ugly, that's the problem. Thanks for you kindly response.

Comment: give static height to child layout that will create distance between two child items than it will not show ugly

Comment: Hi gothion, Have your problem being solved.I am facing a similar issue while setting a common background(9-patch image) for all childItems. Please help me if you have found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In childview layout ( child_.xml ) put in main layout background property.

like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

It changes only background of childviews.

Comment: I have tried this,and it fails to meet the requirement. as this is setting the each child item one by one not in a whole style. as is known, in childview layout you actually can only do things for the item. and can not do things towards the whole children in a group. however thank you Very much.

Answer (score 0):

Set background to the layout/child which you must be inflating in adapter,not to the parent layout.